# Better solution for changing children color on parent hover

Tags: css, colors, hover

Is there very better one line crossbrowser solution to change children text colour via css?
Need to make all text red on hover div

html:

```
<div><span class="gray">I'm a lion!</span><span>Arrrrr!!!</span></div>
```

css:

```
div {color:black};
.gray {color:gray;}
div:hover {color:red;}
```

I thought only this

```
div:hover, div:hover .gray {color:red;}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

your own...

> `div:hover, div:hover .gray {color:red;}`

...is as good a solution as any, really. If you want to match other classes/elements as well you can use a star;

```
div:hover, div:hover * { color:red; }
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/h5BaU/

Comment: That is pretty simple. Yes I would say that's the simplest solution. It is not possible to match both an element and its children in the same selection (e.g. `div:hover && *`) so `div:hover, div:hover *` is both semantic and simple. Give the man the accept!

Comment: Perfect Solutions